# Postgres fails to connect to a solr Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, solr

I'm creating a Docker environment for rails development, but I'm having some difficulties with postgres and solr connecting to each other and am looking for guidance on how to fix it.

I have already created a docker-compose file, and the rails environment for viewing some pages. This is my docker-compose file:

```
app:
  build: .
  command: rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - postgres
    - solr
postgres:
  image: postgres:10.7
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
solr:
  image: solr:8.1.1
  ports:
    - "8983:8983"
  links:
    - postgres
```

However, any rake tasks like rake db:seed or rake db:populate:all fail with errors saying 
`Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:8983 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 8983)`

I would expect that port to be available, as on my computer I can go to localhost:8983/solr and am able to see the solr admin window, but for some reason postgres is unable to find solr when I run the rake commands. Any help would be appreciated with this, as I am currently stuck and don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 points here:

1. `--link` was deprecated, I suggest you delete all `--links` configure in `docker-compose.yaml`. Compose will setup a custom bridge for you and automatically add dns which make your service could visit each other, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#manage-a-user-defined-bridge)
2. In `app` service, for your rails code, I guess you use something like `localhost:8983` to visit `solr service`. You could change the code to use `solr:8983`, then internal dns will guide your app to find the `solr` service.